# How to check if logins are enabled?

Tags: advantage-database-server

So I can call `sp_ModifyDatabase( 'LOGINS_DISABLED','False' )` to modify the state of `LOGINS_DISABLED`, but I can't find how you check the current state of the setting. Anyone know where that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [system.dictionary](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/master_system_dictionary.htm) system table contains that information:

```
SELECT Logins_Disabled FROM system.dictionary;
```

Comment: Should have thought to check that.  Thanks.